# Unity 5 Ball Wont Move No Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple default unity 3d sphere it has a script attached to it using the rigid-body component when i use the arrow keys (set in input) it is meant to move but it does nothing no console errors nothing here is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody PhysicsRB;
public float speed;

void Start ()
{
    speed = 5;
    PhysicsRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Fixedupdate () {
    float MoveH = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float MoveV = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (MoveH, 0.0f, MoveV);

    PhysicsRB.AddForce (movement * speed);

}       
}
```

Comment: You should really do Unity's [Roll-A-Ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) it gives step by step video instructions on how do do exactly what you are doing and each video also has a complete copy of the code to check as a refrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change "Fixedupdate" to "FixedUpdate". Also make sure the file name is the same as the class name. In your example, your script should be called PlayerController.cs.

Comment: im new how do i do that

Comment: oh i see i have ticked it